# jquery doesn't give selected option of a dropbox

Tags: jquery, django, forms

I have a jquery js code in a template like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("select").change(function(){
            var str = $('select option:selected').text();
                alert(str);
            });
        });
</script>
```

and, a select form which is handled by the js code above:

```
class GrupEklemeFormu(forms.Form):
    GORL = (
        (1, ("Global")),
        (2, ("Lokal")),
    )
    g_or_l = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GORL)
```

When I select Global or Local in the page, str becomes "GlobalGlobal" or "GlobalLokal". What is the reason for that? How can I get rid of the error. Thanks..

Comment: Your indentation is off, and that's the source of all evil strange things.

Comment: Don't you get the selected value of a select field using `$('select').val()`?

Comment: $('select').val() works as expected (1 and 2), but .text() combines the strings.